# How to add whitespace in before specific words in LaTeX-table content

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

my question has been removed in fact I have answered in the comment what I'm asking is totally different from the previous question.

```
 \documentclass{article}


    \begin{document}

    \begin{sidewaystable}
\centering

\caption{Summary of transposable elements  }
\label{tab:Table1_SummaryTEs}

\footnotesize

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  S[table-format=7.0]
  S[table-format=9.0]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=7.0]
  S[table-format=9.0]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=7.0]
  S[table-format=9.0]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=7.0]
  S[table-format=9.0]
  S[table-format=2.2]
}
\toprule

Order &
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{rom} &
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{act} &
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{ers} &
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{cos} \\
\cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{5-7} \cmidrule{8-10} \cmidrule{11-13}
& {Number} & {L (bp)} & {\%}  & {Number} & {L (bp)} & {\%} & {Number} & {L (bp)} & {\%} & {Number} & {L (bp)} & {\%} \\
\midrule

\multicolumn{10}{@{}l}{\itshape Class I} \\
SINEs:               & 255687    & 30551159 & 1.52            & 257887  & 31080491  & 1.56             & 261248   &  31533761  & 1.57                    & 258371           & 30783770    &1.42 \\
Alu/B1              & 0 & 0     & 0.00          & 0  & 0   & 0.00                        & 0       & 0      & 0.00                         & 0                &0            & 0.00  \\
    MIRs                 & 247894 & 30250569     & 1.51           & 249065  & 30760408   & 1.54            & 251376   & 31188301      & 1.55                 & 248923       &30437726         &1.40  \\
LINEs:               & 498628 & 207732214   & 10.37           & 501561  & 211005106  & 10.59           &516019    &220321176   &10.97                      & 543212      &226312996     &10.42  \\
LINE1               & 338909 & 163725095   & 8.17             & 342054  & 166954821   & 8.38           &354388    &175466399   &8.73                       &382755      &182566388       &8.40  \\
LINE2               & 133681  & 37311794    & 1.86            & 133693  & 37430629   &1.88             &135350    &38013575    &1.89                      &134657      &37312366         &1.72 \\
L3/CR1              & 16230   &3946140     & 0.20             & 16295   & 3952685  &0.20               &16386    &3999393     &0.20                      &16301         &3896521         &0.18 \\
RTE                 & 8327   & 2349410      & 0.12            & 8280   & 2342043   & 0.12              &8320    &2362314     &0.12                       &8391        &2315634      &0.11 \\

LTR elements:        & 2368202 & 360743057   & 18.00         &2138613 & 331038087   & 16.61           &2043931   &305371407   &15.20                     &2399880      &376465663   &17.33 \\
ERVL                 & 603471 & 94653879   & 4.72            & 535533 & 89635873  &4.50               &457960   &74681407   &3.72                        &589003      &95266242     &4.39 \\
ERVL-MaLRs            & 936686 & 137736037  & 6.87           & 757066 & 122605363  &6.15              &683557   &105114613   &5.23                       &927914      &138867517    &6.39 \\
ERV\_classI            & 401868 & 69495491  &3.47            & 476978 &72572164  &3.64                &458525   &72184510   &3.59                        &442380      &80571827     & 3.71\\
ERV\_classII           & 179048 & 21382713  &1.07            & 143640 & 16451857  & 0.83              &146189     &18906035   &0.94                      &198036        &22430344   &1.03 \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]

\multicolumn{10}{@{}l}{\itshape Class II} \\
DNA transposons:    & 259000 &53746062  & 2.68             & 261351 & 54598424  & 2.74                     &264855  &55556571  &2.77                   & 265748      &54859043     &2.53 \\
hAT-Charlie    &153463 & 28637685  & 1.43                 & 154577 & 29132748 & 1.46                      &156022  & 29603550  &1.47                   & 156955       &29239810    &1.35  \\
TcMar-Tigger    &36981 & 11185164  & 0.56                  & 38120 & 11441081 &0.57                      &39444   &11766559  &   0.59                  & 38989       &11514055   &0.53 \\
Rolling-circles    & 659955 & 72981412  &3.64               & 803681 & 84486255 & 4.24                      &889437   &94191508  & 4.69                 & 738026       &79989304   &3.68 \\
\midrule
Unclassified.      & 3128 & 509710  & 0.03                 & 3147 & 512316 & 0.03                          &3191   &518292  & 0.03                     & 3167       &510872   &0.02  \\

\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
Total & 7101158& 726470712  & 36.25
& 6821541 & 712929637  & 35.78
& 6686198 & 707734238  & 35.22
& 7352708 & 769117479  & 35.41
\end{tabular*}

\end{sidewaystable}
    \end{document}
```

my question simply is how can I add whitespace inside latex table content

as the example below:

[image]

and the required results should be like:

[image]

Comment: I'd probably do that by introducing a new column. The first column of your table would then contain "LINE", "LTR" and "SINE" and the second column "L1", "L2" etc.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @BambOo i have done this earlier and they consider it duplicated question, kindly see the question i edited it

Comment: @moewe would you answer it in a practice. as long I have added the codes of my table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this ?
I simply added a column and some `\multicolumn{}{}{}` to the appropriate cells

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering

\caption{Summary of transposable elements }
\label{tab:Table1}

\footnotesize

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  l
  S[table-format=7.0]
  S[table-format=9.0]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=7.0]
  S[table-format=9.0]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=7.0]
  S[table-format=9.0]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=7.0]
  S[table-format=9.0]
  S[table-format=2.2]
}
\toprule

\multicolumn{2}{l}{Order} &
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{rom} &
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{act} &
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{erus} &
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{cos} \\
\cmidrule{3-5} \cmidrule{6-8} \cmidrule{9-11} \cmidrule{12-14}
& & {N} & {L (bp)} & {\%}  & {N} & {L (bp)} & {\%} & {N} & {L (bp)} & {\%} & {N} & {L (bp)} & {\%} \\
\midrule

\multicolumn{14}{@{}l}{\itshape Class I} \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{SINEs:}               & 255687    & 30551159 & 1.52            & 257887  & 31080491  & 1.56             & 261248   &  31533761  & 1.57                    & 258371           & 30783770    &1.42 \\
&Alu/B1               & 0 & 0     & 0.00                       & 0  & 0   & 0.00                        & 0       & 0      & 0.00                                       & 0       &0    & 0.00  \\
&MIRs                 & 247894 & 30250569     & 1.51           & 249065  & 30760408   & 1.54            & 251376   & 31188301      & 1.55                 & 248923       &30437726    &1.40  \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{LINEs:}               & 498627 & 207732214   & 10.37           & 501561  & 211005106  & 10.59           &516019  &220321176   &10.97                      & 543212      &226312996    &10.42  \\
&LINE1               & 338909 & 163725095   & 8.17             & 342054  & 166954821   & 8.38           &354388  &175466399   &8.73                       &382755      &182566388     &8.40  \\
&LINE2               & 133681  & 37311794    & 1.86            & 133693  & 37430629   &1.88             &135350   &38013575    &1.89                      &134657      &37312366      &1.72 \\
&L3/CR1              & 16230   &3946140     & 0.20             & 16295   & 3952685  &0.20               &16386    &3999393     &0.20                      &16301         &3896521     &0.18 \\
&RTE                 & 8327   & 2349410      & 0.12            & 8280   & 2342043   & 0.12              &8320    &2362314     &0.12                       &8391        &2315634     &0.11 \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{LTR elements}        & 2368202 & 360743057   & 18.00         &2138613 & 331038087   & 16.61           &2043931   &305371407   &15.20                     &2399880      &376465663   &17.33 \\
\midrule
& ERVL                 & 603471 & 94653879   & 4.72            & 535533 & 89635873  &4.50               &457960   &74681407   &3.72                        &589003      &95266242     &4.39 \\
& ERVL-MaLRs            & 936686 & 137736037  & 6.87           & 757066 & 122605363  &6.15              &683557   &105114613   &5.23                       &927914      &138867517    &6.39 \\
& ERV\_classI           & 401868 & 69495491  &3.47            & 476978 &72572164  &3.64                &458525   &72184510   &3.59                        &442380      &80571827     & 3.71\\
&ERV\_classII           & 179048 & 21382713  &1.07            & 143640 & 16451857  & 0.83              &146189     &18906035   &0.94                      &198036        &22430344   &1.03 \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]

\multicolumn{14}{@{}l}{\itshape Class II} \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{DNA transposons:}    & 259000 &53746062  & 2.68             & 261351 & 54598424  & 2.74                     &264855  &55556571  &2.77                   & 265748      &54859043     &2.53 \\
\midrule
& hAT-Charlie    &153463 & 28637685  & 1.43                 & 154577 & 29132748 & 1.46                      &156022  & 29603550  &1.47                   & 156955       &29239810    &1.35  \\
& TcMar-Tigger    &36981 & 11185164  & 0.56                  & 38120 & 11441081 &0.57                      &39444   &11766559  &   0.59                  & 38989       &11514055   &0.53 \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Rolling-circles}    & 659955 & 72981412  &3.64               & 803681 & 84486255 & 4.24                      &889437   &94191508  & 4.69                 & 738026       &79989304   &3.68 \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Unclassified.}      & 3128 & 509710  & 0.03                 & 3147 & 512316 & 0.03                          &3191   &518292  & 0.03                     & 3167       &510872   &0.02  \\

\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{10}{@{}l}{\itshape Total} \\
& 0 & 0  & 0.00
& 0 & 0  & 0.00
& 0 & 0  & 0.00
\end{tabular*}

\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: dear, this is exactly what I'm trying to apply to my table, i would like to do the same into all the subclasses i have highlighted in the picture above.

Comment: i tried to apply the methods into other subclasses but an error occurred,

Comment: @BioInfo basically, the `\multicolumn{2}{pos}{content}` merges `2` columns of the same line and places the `content` in the merged celle with a `pos` alignment. So if you want to have a *indented* content just put and empty column first then your `content` in the second one, which reads a `{} & content` (the `{}` may be removed, as I did in my answer)

Comment: @BioInfo I just updated my answer

Comment: The last line is probably lacking a leading `&` since I added a column to the table